# How to move an object from point A to point B in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a character that needs to move from point A to point B by pressing the Space button.

```
void Move()
    {
        isMove = false;
        Vector2 myPos = transform.position;
        Vector2 JumpPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 1.5f, transform.position.z);

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(myPos, JumpPos, Time.deltaTime * 2);
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(JumpPos, myPos, Time.deltaTime * 2);

        isMove = true;
    }
```

but this is doesn't work. What is doing wrong?

Comment: Hi! First question --- how are you invoking this procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Unity will check your script to find an Update() method and call it once during the production of each frame. (This will happen many times per second.) Here you can check for input, like so:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    Debug.Log("Space key was pressed.");
}
```

Suppose you want to instantly step to the destination. You might do something like so:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    var JumpPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 1.5f, transform.position.z);
    transform.position = JumpPos;
}
```

But if you want a gradual transition, then we need to start thinking about state and the big picture. There are many strategies to do this and off the shelf kits. I'll do this like an example.

Suppose that when we tap space, we want to start a transition to the destination that takes place over some amount of time.

Personally, I could add a private member variable to the class like this:

`Vector3? destination = null;`

Then, in `Update()`, when the space bar is pressed, I can set a destination:

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        destination = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 1.5f, transform.position.z);
    }
```

Then, after that, still in the Update method, we'll take care of the transition:

```
    if (destination.HasValue) {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, destination.Value, 1.0f);
    }
```

And finally, if we're actually at the destination, we can stop the process:

```
    if (destination.HasValue && destination.Value == transform.position)
    {
        destination = null;
    }
}
```

And this works. It might not fit your big picture but I think it's enough to get you in the right headspace!